# Does anyone know how I could display on a menu that randomly picks up 1 of 6 items (like sword/shield/etc.) and then adds/displays it to a backpack?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is what I've tried so far including my entire project code for the small class project game. Honestly struggle with arrays and don't even know where to start. The project requirements were to Display a menu (use a switch statement to implement the menu) of actions. Then to display the user has chosen to attack or not attack. Then pick up an item randomly and add the random item to one of 6 items in an array named knapSack. Then display the user picked up the item and its random name along with an option to display the Knap Sacks contents (sorted). I'm actually dropping out of computer science, but if I don't pass this assignment I fail so man I'm begging LMAO.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{

 //Variables
 const double stepForest = 50;
 const double stepDungeon = 100;
 const double stepHouse = 4000;
 const double stepMaze = 6000;

//Direction of walking
string North;
string South;
string East;
string West;


//Direction
string direction;
double step;
double steps;


//Asking how many steps
string sSteps;
int nSteps = 0;

  //Not allowing negative steps
  while (cout << "How many steps are you taking? " << endl
  && !(cin >> nSteps) || nSteps < 0)

  {
  cin.clear ();
  cout << "ERROR: Illegal input!" << endl;

   }


  //Asking direction user is moving in
  cout << "Which direction? (North, West, South, or East) " << endl;
  cin >> direction;


   //Steps for forest
   if (steps >= stepForest && direction == "North");
   {

    cout << "You have reached the forest. " << endl;

    }

     //Steps for dungeon
     if (steps >= stepDungeon && direction == "South")
     {

     cout << "You have reached the dungeon. " << endl;

      }

  //Steps for house
  else if (steps >= stepHouse && direction == "East")
   {

     cout << "You have reached the house. " << endl;

  }

  //Steps for maze
  else if (steps >= stepMaze && direction == "West")
   {

    cout << "You have reached the maze. " << endl;
   }

   {
   //For menu
   int input ();
   void output (float);

   //Drop down meny bar selections
   float result;
    int choice, num;
    cout << ("Press 1 to attack\n");
    cout << ("Press 2 to not attack\n");
    cout << ("Press 3 to pick up an item\n");
    cout << ("Press 4 to display Knapsack contents\n");
    cout << ("Enter your choice:\n");
    choice = input ();


   //Attack option
   switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
   {
    cout << ("You have chosen to attack\n");
    cout << ("Your character has attacked\n");
    output (result);
    break;
  }
   //No attack option
    case 2:
  {
    cout << ("You have chosen not to attack\n");
    cout << ("You do nothing\n");
    output (result);
    break;
  }

   //Picking up item option
    case 3:
     {
     cout << ("You have picked up an item\n");
     cout << ("The item has been added to Knapsack\n");


     //Random array output for knapSack items
     char sorteio1[50][11] =
      { "Sword", "Scarf", "Spear", "Knife", "Katana", "Bow" };
     int i;

      i = rand () % 50;

     cout << ("%s\n", sorteio1[i]);
     cout << ("The item you picked up was\n"); //This is where I wanted to insert the random 
     array
     cout << (int ());



   // Maybe: "knapsack[count] = loot"       *****
   // loot= randomItems[randomNumber]      *****



    //Knapsack contents
    output (result);
    break;
  }
    case 4:
  {
    printf ("1.Sword \n");
    printf ("2.Scarf \n");
    printf ("3.Spear \n");
    printf ("4.Knife \n");
    printf ("5.Katana \n");
    printf ("6.Bow \n");
    output (result);
    break;
  }


  printf ("wrong Input\n");

    }
}


  int number;
  scanf ("%d", &number);
  return (number);


  {
  //To quit game
  int choice, num;
   bool quit = false;
  cout << "Would you like to quit (y/n)? ";
  cin >> choice;

  //If player chooses to quit
   if (choice == 'y')
   {
   cout << "Goodbye you have chosen to quit the game. See you next time! ";
    }
    else
    {
    quit = true;

      //If player chooses not to quit, but its the end fo the program anyways so
      if (choice == 'n')
     {
      cout <<
     "You have chosen not to quit the game. But this is the end anyways! ";
      }
     quit = false;
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and I'm not really sure exactly what you're asking for help with. Can you try and focus on one thing? Why do you use `scanf` sometimes and `>>` in others? Why mix `printf` and `<<`?

Comment: Focus on one step at a time, write functions for each step, and test those functions individually. Come back when you have identified a single task for which you need help, and ask a specific question about what is giving you trouble. (If you ask at a good level of abstraction, you might not need to list your project requirements.)